# In SAS: Standardizing values by group when number of missing values within group outnumber non-missing values

Tags: sas

I am looking to standardize values of variable `V2` along variable `V1`. I would like to replace all missing with any non-missing value within group V1. The non-missing values are standardized, and might occur more than once within a group.

Have:

```
V1    V2
----------
 1    100
 1    -
 1    -    
 1    -
 1    -
 1    -
 1    100
 2    -
 2    -
 2    200
 3    -
 3    300
 3    300
 3    -
 3    -
 3    -
```

Want:

```
V1    V2
----------
 1    100
 1    100
 1    100    
 1    100
 1    100
 1    100
 1    100
 2    200
 2    200
 2    200
 3    300
 3    300
 3    300
 3    300
 3    300
 3    300
```

I used:

```
Proc stdize data=have out=want missing=mean reponly;
By V1;
Var V2;
Run;
```

Though this fails to fill in all missing values by the mean of the non-missing values. Many missing values remain.

Within most groups there are more missing values than there are non-missing values. I expect this might make standardization by mean impossible.

How can I achieve the desired result when the majority of values within a group are missing, but the non-misisng values are still standardized?

Comment: Did you read the SAS log?  Did you get a message like this?
WARNING: The scale estimator for variable V2 is less than or equal to 0. Variable V2 will not be standardized and a missing
         value is assigned to its scale estimator.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      V1=1

Comment: I was prompted that exact message in the log.

Comment: Your example data shows the v2 values being the same across all records for each group. Does that reflect your actual data structure?

Comment: Yes. It's the same value across each group.

Comment: Did you mean to say you want to impute missing values such that each group has a "user10712739" distribution ?

Comment: Are the conditions arbitrary? I want to replace all values within a group by the first non-missing value encountered within that group. I could order the observations by V1 and V2, so that each first observation within a group is a non-missing value and then fill forward this value within that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using a double DOW-loop approach:

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.v1);
    set have;
    by v1;
    if not(missing(v2)) and missing(fill_value) then fill_value = v2;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if missing(v2) then v2 = fill_value;
  end;
  drop fill_value;
run;
```